# The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred, but only sometimes

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm using TypeScript to write my Discord bot, and its main purpose is sending cute axolotl pictures.

It uses a REST API to do this, but it's on free hosting so it can be quite slow sometimes, especially when it hasn't been used in a while. So to prevent the same issue [Nextcord (discord.py fork) - How can I return to Discord that a command is currently running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384881/nextcord-discord-py-fork-how-can-i-return-to-discord-that-a-command-is-curre) had, I'm deferring the reply. However, this only seems to work sometimes, other times it crashes the code because it's trying to edit a non-deferred reply?

Relevant part of ImageCommand.ts:

```
export default (client: Client, commandsArray: Array<CommandInterface>) => {
    commandsArray.push({
        name: "image",
        description: "Sends you a cute axolotl picture from Reddit.",
        executor: async (interaction: ChatInputCommandInteraction, client: Client) => {
            interaction.deferReply();

            const channel: TextChannel = interaction.channel as TextChannel;

            let payload = "?minImages=1&flair=Just Showing Off ";
            if (channel.nsfw) payload += "&nsfw=1"; // If for some reason a cute axolotl picture is marked as NSFW, only show it when sent from a NSFW channel

            const post = (await Axios.get("https://axolotlapi.kirondevcoder.repl.co/reddit" + payload)).data.data[0];
            
            const images: Array<ImageInterface> = post.media.filter((m: any) => m.kind === "image");
            const image: string = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)].url;

            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(post.title)
                .setAuthor({ name: `u/${post.author}`, url: `https://reddit.com/u/${post.author}` })
                .setURL(post.link)
                .setTimestamp(post.created_utc * 1000)
                .setImage(image)
            ;

            interaction.editReply({ embeds: [ embed ]});
        }
    });
}
```

I tried deferring the reply like in [Nextcord (discord.py fork) - How can I return to Discord that a command is currently running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384881/nextcord-discord-py-fork-how-can-i-return-to-discord-that-a-command-is-curre), but that only works sometimes. When it does not work, it just crashes the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ChatInputCommandInteraction>#deferReply` returns a promise which you are not awaiting.

Change

```
interaction.deferReply();
```

to

```
await interaction.deferReply();
```

It is also worth noting the type for the interaction should be `ChatInputCommandInteraction<"cached">` not just `ChatInputCommandInteraction` since the interaction is already cached. ([source](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/dc142c47e4021d6d37712453cc2fad6e4fe4e9f7/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts#L1091))

[documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.7.1/class/ChatInputCommandInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply)

Comment: Thanks, awaiting deferring the reply seems to have worked!